# Define fonts for re-use in python fpdf

Tags: python-3.x, fpdf

I´m building PDF document in python with fpdf. Fonts are set in the following way:

```
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 20)
```

However, this seems a bit unclear if I have to change the font several times (for headings, sub headings, regular text and so on). So I was trying to define fonts upfront in the following form:

```
heading = ["arial", "B", 20]
sub_heading = ["arial", "B", 15]
```

And then use the defined fonts later:

```
pdf.set_font(heading)
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\project\main.py", line 112, in <module>
    pdf.set_font(heading)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\project\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 567, in set_font
    family=family.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

So I was wondering, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
pdf.set_font(*heading)
```